# How to detect non modifier key press combination?

Tags: delphi, textbox, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-events, onkeypress

I have the following problem in Delphi (but it might be taken as a general programming question).

I would like to handle somehow a key press event for more than one non-modifier key combination, for example for shortcuts like <kbd>A</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> or <kbd>D</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> or <kbd>D</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>.

I know how to handle shortcuts with modifier keys like for instance <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> or <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, but how can I detect non-modifier key press combination ?

Comment: No there's no particular event handler, you have to track the key sequences manually. (BTW, please don't shout)

Comment: And please don't use information that belongs in tags in your subjects. The tag system is very good here, and doesn't need help (especially when SHOUTED). Use the tags - that's what they're for.

Answer (score 8):

Each individual keystroke generates separate `OnKeyDown`, `OnKeyPress`, and `OnKeyUp` events.  So you have three choices:

1. keep track of each key that is currently held down.  For each key you receive, set a flag for it in the `OnKeyDown` event and clear the flag for it in the corresponding `OnKeyUp` event.  When you get an `OnKeyDown` event for <kbd>D</kbd>, check if you already flagged <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>F</kbd>, <kbd>G</kbd>, etc.  The `OnKeyDown` and `OnKeyUp` events will also tell you the state of the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, <kbd>ALT</kbd>, and <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> keys.
2. use the Win32 API `GetKeyboardState()`, `GetKeyState()` or `GetAsyncKeyState()` functions. When you get an `OnKeyDown` event for <kbd>D</kbd>, ask the OS if <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>F</kbd>, <kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, etc are currently held down.
3. for some sequences, you might use `RegisterHotKey()` and let the OS track the keys for you.  When a registered sequence is detected, you will receive a `WM_HOTKEY` message.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will prove your method, especially for point 1 and 2! Thanks!

Comment: If someone is moving the mouse (think of a laptop touchpad--many a time I've hit it by accident while typing) method #1 might fail.  I'm not aware of anything that could fail #2.

Comment: @LorenPechtel: Just interested. How would it fail? The individual keyboard events would still be fired and you can track them?

Comment: I thinks can i track them with flags.. But i haven't thinked to Loren's problem, infact if someone will move the mouse, the method #1 fail..

Comment: @MarjanVenema: The events will happen but if the mouse moves they might not happen to the window that's looking for them.

Comment: @LorenPechtel: hmm. Just because the mouse moves? Aren't keyboard events linked to input focus? Would be very strange if moving the mouse would change that. It would mean that I would have to keep my mouse within the bounds of an edit box at all times or my keystrokes could end up elsewhere? It seems to me that it would take a click to change (keyboard) input focus and that would be a perfectly valid way to interrupt the key-sequence.

Comment: @MarjanVenema: I've seen programs lose SOME key events when the mouse moved off the program.  It's never happened with my code so I never dug into exactly what was going on.

Comment: @LorenPechtel: ah ok, that's interesting. Possibly some over-eager trigger-happy (tool)window. Wouldn't surprise me, plenty of programs around that want to stay-on-top of everybody else regardless of user-wishes  :-)